# Regex for both website url versions with wildcard

Tags: regex

I'm trying to add in allowed urls in a watchguard firebox webblocker list using regular expression. I'm trying to keep my list short by allowing one entry to apply to both www and non-www versions of a site including subdomains. I'm currently using the following:

`(www\.)?ups\.com/*`

Which works great for both versions plus subdomains, but has an issue as it allows other sites through that end their domain with ups.com such as jobs-ups.com

How can I make the regular expression know that if there is no subdomain that the url is only going to be ups.com without any other letters before the u, so it will block sites like jobs-ups.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the caret `^` to accomplish this

```
^(?:www\.)?ups\.com\/
```

### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bN0GrI/3)

The caret forces the check at the **start of the string**. This means it will not match in mid-string, which is what you are wanting.

Not familiar with firebox at all, but *generally* you should escape your periods and forward slashes. You would also *generally* use a non-capturing group as well. But if this is simple regex, you can still preserve your original formatting:

```
^(www.)?ups.com/*
```

Comment: Did make mine as code so it took out the backslashes, here is what I tried which still didn't work `\b(?:www\.)?ups\.com\/*`. Watchguard mentions to use Perl-compatable regular expression

Comment: Tried it before you edit. Gave `^(?:www\.)?ups\.com\/` a go, but still allows jobs-ups.com through. Here is their info on it: https://www.watchguard.com/help/docs/fireware/12/en-US/Content/en-US/proxies/general/regular_expressions_c.html

Comment: Very strange @Dan. I just gave the documentation a quick lookover and it states that it uses "real" regex (as in not just simple wildcards). This is from docs: `To match the beginning or end of a line, you must use an anchor. The caret (^) matches the beginning of a line`. I'll think about what changes you can make.

Comment: This is very "hacky", but the above regex **should work**. So you can try this ugly method and see if it accomplishes what you need: `^(?:www\.ups|ups)\.com.*$`